# Inconsistent read violation when using game state machine

Tags: c++, debugging

I am getting some very inconsistent read violation errors with my FSM. It is very hard to reproduce but it always happens when the FSM is switching between states. It breaks at this block:

```
void MenuState::update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_gameObjects.size(); i++)
   {
        assert(m_gameObjects[i] != NULL); //the program breaks at this line
        m_gameObjects[i]->update();
   }
}
```

It's very strange because it occurs right when I am switching from my "MenuState" to my "PlayState". Using console outputs, I know for I fact that the state is changed to the PlayState, but the FSM still calls the update function from the MenuState.

```
void GameStateMachine::changeState(GameState *pState)
{
if (!m_gameStates.empty())
{
    if (m_gameStates.back()->getStateID() == pState->getStateID())
    {
        return;
    }
    if (m_gameStates.back()->onExit())
    {
        delete m_gameStates.back();
        m_gameStates.pop_back();
    }
}

m_gameStates.push_back(pState);
m_gameStates.back()->onEnter(); 
}
```

Change state when button is pressed:

```
if (InputHandler::Instance()->getMouseButtonState(LEFT) && m_bReleased)
{
    m_currentFrame = CLICKED;

    m_callback(); //this callback calls the FSM changeState member

    m_bReleased = false;
}
```

I've looked all through my code and I can't find the error, and this error only occurs 10% of the time I change states, which makes this whole thing even more confusing. Any tips or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: The actual code causing the problem isn't present here. Just look for code that assigns into the `m_gameObjects` vector. If that fails, use your debugger and set a data breakpoint so you can catch the exact line that nulls out the element.

Comment: I think the problem ended up being in the update loop. Even though the state was changed the loop would run through another iteration and would attempt to access "m_gameObjects" even though it was deleted when the state was changed. What I ended up doing was checking if "m_GameObjects" was NULL, and if so break out of the loop.

Comment: nevermind, this didn't work since the debugger says that m_gameObjects's size is huge so I'm not sure what's going on

Comment: @michael You code is incomplete, but I assume `m_gameObjects` is a `std::vector`. A vector suddenly getting a nonsensical size is often caused by an invalid write that trampled its storage. Try to find the exact point at which the size blows up.

Comment: Use the debugger to inspect the values _inside_ the vector, if they don't make sense, it's probably because the menustate got deleted. Then inspect the stack trace to see why it's even called while it should not.

Comment: The problem was that the loop continued to iterate even though the state was deleted, causing the read violation. I "solved" this by having a Boolean which holds if the state is the current state before updating. Do you think this is a legitimate solution?